# What are extrinsic and intrinsic flavour production?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

In terms of Feynman diagrams, what are extrinsic and intrinsic flavour production?

See for example this paper [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2766) (p.2).

Comment: Where have you found such terms? Could you provide a link or a reference?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti You are right, a reference should be given. I have added the link to the paper where the term was used.

Comment: One assumes intrinsic means part of the pdfs and extrinsic not.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Could you please specify what you mean by 'part of the PDF'? Do you mean that in terms of parton evolution in the intrinsic case the heavy quarks contribute to the evolution and in the extrinsic case they don't? And if so, how exactly do they contribute?

Comment: I think so; I am not an expert. I would even expect an intrinsic charm pdf, just like s, u,d, but You'd best go to a manual like CTEQ or so...  like https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1236 or https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-016-3941-z